# WinCE application continuous running! cannot close application

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-ce

I'm using Wince 6.0 and application is developed in C#. Application consists of a small GUI   and some COM, TCP interfaces. Everything was working fine, I created new thread and everything   went wrong. Now I cannot see GUI and cannot close application communication is continuously   happening. I tried to format Nand Flash but it shows message cannot be formatted! what to do?   How I can stop/delete this application?

Comment: post your new thread code here..which is causing the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application created a background thread that is not terminating.  Use the Remote Process Viewer (under the Start Menu for Visual Studio 2008) to stop the current running instance.  To prevent it from happening again, make sure you set `IsBackground` on the Thread to `true`.  Generally I also have the Thread watch an instance boolean variable for a shutdown request as well.  I set that variable on Dispose of the Thread's creator.

Answer (score 0):

You can do clean booting to clears all memory, including persistent storage. you can find more on this in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee490762%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx)